# What could be a better way to achieve Checked Exception handling in mapping functions passed to Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, exception, stream, java-stream

I have a simple scenario which I am trying to code without being clumsy and without writing unreadable multiline lambdas.

```
public class StreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hellow", "world");
        Stream<String> stream = list.stream().map(StreamTest::exceptionThrowingMappingFunction);

    }

    public static String exceptionThrowingMappingFunction(String s) throws Exception {
        if (s.equals("world")) {
            throw new Exception("world is doomed");
        }
        return s + " exists";
    }
}
```

What I would like to have are the following options:

1. Fail the whole stream if the exception is thrown
2. Skip the value and continue with the rest of the stream if exception occurs

I know about popular ways of dealing with this, like throwing a RuntimeException in a custom FunctionalInterface or just handling the exception inline.

But is there some way, where I can extend Streams and just write a stream like StreamWithExceptionHandling extends Stream. Which also accepts an ExceptionHandler and just implements the above behaviour?

Thanks for taking your time to read this one.

Comment: which approach are you trying either 1 or 2 ?

Comment: I am open to doing any solution, if I dont have to write a inline handler in the lambda call.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a sample solution and posting it to Code Review. Your problem might be a good fit.

Lambdas are useful for one liners. For the rest: don't feel bad about just defining a class or a method.

For option 2, map the value into a result object that contains operation status and return value and then filter by status. You'll avoid introducing non-standard behaviour to the streams API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompletionStages to help out in this scenario. They have a good interface for handling exceptional flows.

So, convert your streamed value to an already completed CompletableFuture, as a map step in the stream, then map it again to CompletionStage.thenApply, which returns a new CompletionStage that holds any exceptions for you. You can then filter the unwanted exceptional completion stages out of the stream, or include other other processing steps if you want (like logging the exception, for example).

And of course you can map the value back out of a CompletionStage into the actual completed value easily enough.

It’s one way to do it at least, without trying to write your own streams interface.